# RxJS fromEvent target type issue (Angular 13)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

When working with fromEvent and ViewChild I receive the following error in the terminal:

> The last overload gave the following error. Argument of type
>  ElementRef | undefined  is not assignable to parameter of type
> JQueryStyleEventEmitter<any, unknown> |
> ArrayLike<JQueryStyleEventEmitter<any, unknown>>

I can't understand or find a reason online why fromEvent is expecting a JQueryStyleEventEmitter type as the first argument in fromEvent?

My rxjs version: 7.5.7

From the rxjs docs:

> Target : The DOM EventTarget, Node.js EventEmitter, JQuery-like event target,
> NodeList or HTMLCollection to attach the event handler to.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('startPolling', { static: false }) startButton: ElementRef | undefined;
  startClick$: any;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.startClick$ = fromEvent(this.startButton, 'click');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `this.startButton.nativeElement` to return the native DOM element as the first argument for `fromEvent`.

And you can use the [`!` exclamation mark](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-exclamation-mark-typescript/#:%7E:text=marks%20in%20TypeScript-,What%20is%20the%20TypeScript%20exclamation%20mark%3F,possibility%20of%20it%20being%20undefined.) as a replacement for the declaration of `startButton` with the type `ElementRef | undefined`.

```
@ViewChild('startPolling', { static: false }) startButton!: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.startClick$ = fromEvent(this.startButton.nativeElement, 'click');
}
```

Reference: [Create Observable from Event using FromEvent in Angular](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/create-observable-from-event-using-fromevent-in-angular/)

Comment: this.startButton?.nativeElement resolved the error. However I'm still curious as to why it expected JQueryStyleEventEmitter.